# What's the difference between short term memory and working memory?

Tags: working-memory, short-term-memory

What's the difference between short term memory and working memory? and how does the process work?

Comment: The first question can be answered, but the second is vague and very broad. Can you explain more about what you want to know?

Comment: Related: https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/9198/is-there-a-difference-between-visual-short-term-memory-and-visual-working-memory

Comment: I just want to know how the basics works in an easy example for a better understanding
For exapmle if I see an object for the very first time - it's in my iconical memory, from there it gets into my short term memory, if someone points it out, then by practice or rehearsal, chunking,.. it gets into the long term memory.
I know that the working memory is kind of the pipeline between short term memory and long term memory
but i am not entirely sure how it works?